# I need to run a python program when others try to open a folder

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to run a python program when I try to open my folder.i like to put lock my folder to do this I created a program that verifies the password . All I need here is when I open the folder it should run the program.if the program verifies go in to the folder otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

I would take an approach of *running a batch file* (to run python code) when the particular *folder opening event is triggered* .**Listening “folder opening” events in windows is not easy** as far I know. What you can do is,there are other projects to lock the folder using python. You can update that script in your own way.

[github project](https://github.com/xSynthx/Folder-Locker/blob/master/folder-locker.py)